# Display 'model' stored in .js file in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have this 'model' saved as variable

http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/source/webgl/teapot-model-IFS.js

How to display it now in `draw()` function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? If you are new to webgl here's a tutorial I can recommend: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html it should be enough to get you started

Comment: However if you're not interested in webgl and just want to display the thing on screen then google babylon.js or three.js

Comment: @zoran404 three.js is definitely better, but i need to finish that webgl thing for university laboratory. This is the last thing i have to do, and everywhere i ask people just link documentation instead of answering. I appreciate the help, but webgl is very unintuitive, so i'm stuck for a few days now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but peoole here will only try to help you understand the task, not do the entire task for you. You should try to do it yourself and then come back when you get stuck with something. Make sure to show your code.

Comment: Well, in many cases people do offer solutions to the problems. Sometimes they just link documentation, which helps only if its hard to find documentation.